# UWP group has weird behavior during RunTime

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I am new to XAML for UWP. So I am trying to make 4 group boxes using .XAML. When I attempt to run the code it stretches the group box that makes the GUI look terrible. What in the .XAML could cause something like this?

During design time it looks like:

[image: Design Time]

When I run the code in the Simulator it looks like:

[image: Run time GUI]

.XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
  <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="232"/>
  <ListView x:Name="DatabaseInfo" Header="Database Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" Margin="212,130,551,276" FontFamily="Tahoma" >
     <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="ServerNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Server" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="Server" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115" />
     </StackPanel>

     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="DatabaseNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Database" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="UserNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="UserName" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="UserName" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="PasswordDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Password" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </ListView>
  <ListView x:Name="RabbitMQInfo" Header="Rabbit MQ Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" Margin="564,130,199,350" FontFamily="Tahoma" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
     <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="RabbitMQUserDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="UserName" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="RabbitMQUser" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="RabbitMQPassDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Password" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="RabbitMQPass" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </ListView>
  <ListView x:Name="MachineInfo" Header="Name Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" Margin="212,398,551,125" FontFamily="Tahoma" >
     <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="NameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Name" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </ListView>
  <ListView x:Name="IPAddressInfo" Header="IP Address Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" Margin="564,332,199,156" FontFamily="Tahoma" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
     <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="IPAddressDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="IPAddress" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="IPAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name="PortDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Port" Width="115" Height="25" />
        <TextBox Name="Port" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
     </StackPanel>
  </ListView>
  <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save" Click="btnSave_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,539,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="50"/>
```

Another question I have about UWP applications is do you have to have something special to run the .exe that gets outputted in the Bin folder? When trying to run the .exe as Admin it just crashes and with an unhandled win32 exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I attempt to run the code it stretches the group box that makes the GUI look terrible. What in the .XAML could cause something like this?

You used `Margin` property to control your XAML control's position, it will lead to the messy layout you see.

Please see [Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/) document to learn how to make a good layouts with XAML in UWP.

For example, you could simply use a Grid control to put these controls on different row and column.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="42" Width="232"/>
    <ListView x:Name="DatabaseInfo" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="Database Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" FontFamily="Tahoma" >
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="ServerNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Server" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="Server" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="DatabaseNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Database" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="Database" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="UserNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="UserName" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="UserName" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="PasswordDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Password" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="RabbitMQInfo" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Rabbit MQ Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" FontFamily="Tahoma" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="RabbitMQUserDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="UserName" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="RabbitMQUser" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="RabbitMQPassDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Password" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="RabbitMQPass" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="MachineInfo" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Header="Name Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" FontFamily="Tahoma" >
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="NameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Name" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="IPAddressInfo" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Header="IP Address Info." BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" SelectionMode="None" FontFamily="Tahoma" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewHeaderItem Content="{Binding}" Height="40" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Name="IPAddressDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="IPAddress" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="IPAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="230" Height="30" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="PortDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Port" Width="115" Height="25" />
            <TextBox Name="Port" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="" Height="25" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

> Another question I have about UWP applications is do you have to have something special to run the .exe that gets outputted in the Bin folder? When trying to run the .exe as Admin it just crashes and with an unhandled win32 exception.

UWP runs in sandbox, it's different from the classic desktop application. You cannot directly double click the '.exe' file to start it. When you're coding in visual studio, you could press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start it and debug it. If it has been deployed, you could start it from windows 'Start' menu.

> Tips: Please do not post multiple question in one post next time.

Comment: So how would you include a release .exe for UWP in a installer for a desktop application? If you can't run it unless you are in a sandbox environment.

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer Please check [Package a UWP app with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps)